# NetBeans Swing GUI builder keeps loading

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdialog

I'm trying to learn to use Swing GUI and I'm using NetBeans to arrange the controls. However, when I come to the "Design" tab, it just keeps saying "Loading ..." forever, so I can't really use the builder.

[image: Problem screenshot]

This is just a default NetBeans template, here's the code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * NewJDialog.java
 *
 * Created on May 29, 2015, 5:29:06 PM
 */
package GUI;

/**
 *
 * @author nacho
 */
public class NewJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /** Creates new form NewJDialog */
    public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Code ">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pack();
    }
    // </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                NewJDialog dialog = new NewJDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is NetBeans 7.0.1 in elementary OS Luna 0.2.1 (Ubuntu 12.04).

So, is there any library/package I need to install to render this? I don't know what this problem might come from. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to learn Swing, code it. drag-n-drop will teach you nothing. If you just now start with UI applications, it might be better to learn JavaFX instead.

Comment: @Stultuske could you provide some link to any JavaFx tutorial (except oracle docs), will appriciate it a lot.

Comment: what's wrong with the oracle tutorials?

Comment: @Stultuske I disagree that dragging and dropping teaches nothing.  It certainly shouldn't be the only way to work, but it's a great place to start.

Comment: @cronos2 Java Swing should come fully installed and ready to use in Netbeans.  I have used it successfully for many years in the exact way that you are, except for one detail: I don't use JDialog.  Try using JPanels or JFrames.  Also, whenever this kind of thing happens with the "Loading..." be sure to check your constructors.  Been down this road many times and it's always the constructor.  In your case, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @KSK thanks for your help, but I assume a default file generated by NetBeans should not have that problem. Any other guesses?

Comment: @KSK : the netbeans editor creates unmaintainable crappy code. let's say you have ten buttons in a specific order, and later on, you need to add one somewhere in between.
Either your testers don't know your job, or you'll see the regression bugs piling up.

Comment: @cronos2: did you change anything in the file outside of netbeans?

Comment: @Stultuske nope, that's just the plain default NetBeans JDialog file

Comment: yes, I'm aware it's a netbeans file, but in the end, they're just .java files, it's possible to open them in, for instance, notepad and alter them. only, if this happens, chances are the netbeans editor won't be able to work with them anymore.

Comment: @Stultuske yes, but I hadn't edited it, just default content.

I finally fixed this error by updating to 8.0.2. Thanks everybody for your assistance!